# How to use the extreme value theorem on a vector valued function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My task is this:

Suppose that $A \subset\mathbb{R}^m$ is closed, bounded and that $\textbf{F}:A\to \mathbb{R}^k$ is continious. Show that $\exists ! \: K\in\mathbb{R}:\: \mid\textbf{F}(\textbf{x})\mid \:\leq K \: \forall \: \textbf{x}\in A.$

My work so far (although I'm not sure if this is the right approach):

Since $\textbf{F}:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^k,\ \textbf{F}$ can be written like this:

$\textbf{F}(\textbf{x}) = \left[f_1(\textbf{x}), f_2(\textbf{x}), ...,f_k(\textbf{x}) \right]$ where $f_1, f_2, ...,f_k : \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$.

$\textbf{F}$ is continous $\implies$ $f_1, f_2, ...,f_k$ is continious. 
Since $A$ is closed and bounded then $\exists !\:t_i \in \mathbb{R} : f_i(A) \leq t_i$ for $i\in \mathbb{N}_{\leq \ k}$, according to the extreme value theorem. Let us now define $K^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{k} t_i^2$, then we have that: $$\mid\textbf{F}(\textbf{x})\mid \:= \sqrt{\left[f_1(\textbf{x}) \right]^2 + \left[f_2(\textbf{x}) \right]^2 +...+\left[f_k(\textbf{x}) \right]^2} \leq \sqrt{t_1^2 + t_2^2 +...+ t_k^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k} t_i^2} = \sqrt{K^2} = K.$$

Which is what we wanted to show.

I hope this is correct, but i would like someone to verify/point out any errors that i may have done or give a shorter/better approach to this. My book says nothing about vector valued functions, only functions on the form $f:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your proof looks good. You could shorten it by observing that $g(\bf x) = | \bf F(\bf x)|$ is continuous.

Comment: The exclamation point after the existential quantifier usually indicates the word "unique" which is not the case in your quantified statements.

Comment: Just suppose now you have $K_1, K_2 \mathbb{R}$, such $K_1 \neq K_2$. You will easily see you cannot in the real line. Therefore, $K_1=K_2=K$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Isn't it the case that sup$\{f_i(A)\} = t_i$ for $i = 1,2,...,k$ and that $t_i$ is unique for each $f_i$?

Comment: The supremum is unique, but upper bounds are not.